# Weird jump to top of page behavior with MarkdownDeep

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, markdownsharp, markdowndeep

I am playing with MarkdownDeep .Net/Javascipt Edition for an MVC 3 application. Added it via NuGet. The page renders Markdown sharp box just fine. However I get a weird jump to top of page behavior if any of the icons on the markdown sharp toolbar are clicked. I googled and didn't find anyone else having this issue.
Any thoughts? The script file and css are being loaded properly - no errors in Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the microsoft ajax scripts are included in the page and that the web.config file is configured to use it?  Try something simple like a ajax.beginform to see if it posts the page or if it calls an ajax post.